# How can I get the identity of a row that was just added to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5

Say that I have this code:

```
rentalEaseDataSet.tblCheckbookEntry.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

I want to get the identity of a column from that row I just added. How can I do this? Say the row is called ID.

For reference, I'm using C# and sql server express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that row hasn't actually been saved to the database yet, so it doesn't have a *database* id (so sql server express isn't an issue). You need to use the adapter to save the changes, and then the id of `newRow` should reflect the database.

Comment: The adapter assumes responsibility for changes in both directions, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are dealing with an auto-incremented identity value on the source of the data, you can't do this.  You have to commit the changes to the data source through a data adapter, and then the column that represents the auto incremented id will be updated with the value.